# How to change size of div continously thru touchspin

Tags: javascript

Heres the code i have, ive tried to create a grid thru checkbox and based on the horizontal and vertical attributes of the touchspin value it updates the grid dimensions, heres the code i tried.

```
function displayGrid(){
var grid_Check = document.getElementById('Grid');
var touchspinH = document.getElementById("kt_touchspin_5").value;
var touchspinV = document.getElementById("kt_touchspin_5-1").value;
var touchspinI = document.getElementById("increase");

if(grid_Check.checked == true){
    var wall = document.getElementsByClassName("videoWallContainer");
    var width = $(wall).width();
    var height = $(wall).height();
    
    for (var rows = 0; rows < touchspinH; rows++) {
        for (var columns = 0; columns < touchspinV; columns++) {
            $(".videoWallContainer").append("<div class='grid'></div>");
        };
    };
    
    $(".grid").width(width/touchspinH);
    $(".grid").height(height/touchspinV);
   
    
    $('#kt_touchspin_5').change(updateGridWidth());
    $('#kt_touchspin_5-1').change(updateGridHeight());
    
    function updateGridHeight (){
       var horizontal = $('#kt_touchspin_5').val();
        var gridW =   $(".grid").width();
            $(".grid").width(width/horizontal);
    }
    
     function updateGridWidth  (){
      var vertical = $('#kt_touchspin_5-1').val();
        var gridH =   $(".grid").height();
        $(".grid").height(height/vertical);
    }
}
else {
    $(".grid").remove();
}
}
```

html -

```
CHECKBOX - 
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input position-static col-lg-1 m-2" id="Grid" onclick="displayGrid()">
                  <label  class="col-form-label ">Grid</label> <br>'
TOUCHSPIN - 
 <label class="col-form-label m-2">Horizontal</label>
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <input id="kt_touchspin_5" type="text" class="form-control position-static bootstrap-touchspin-vertical-btn"  name="demo0" placeholder="2" />
                </div>
             <label class="col-form-label m-2">Vertical</label>
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <input id="kt_touchspin_5-1" type="text" class="form-control position-static bootstrap-touchspin-vertical-btn" name="demo0" placeholder="2" />
                </div>
            
            </div>
```

Creating the grid works but the grid only updates whenever i uncheck and recheck the check box but not when i increase the touchspin counter of horizontal and vertical. How do i achieve this?

Comment: You need to do something when the user inputs a value. For example on change.

Comment: yes i did do that